# Is $f(z)=k\cdot\frac{e^z}{z}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let's say we have the following complex function

$$f(z)=k\cdot\frac{e^z}{z}$$

**Is it analytic in some domain?** When substituting with $z=x+iy$, using trigonometry and deriving the function on the form $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ as follows;

$$f(x,y)=k\cdot\frac{e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2}$$

it seems to fail, at least the first of, the Cauchy-Riemann's equations:
$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \text{and} \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

But, intuitively it feels like the function $f(z)$ should be analytic in $\mathbb C / \{ z = 0 \} $. Is this correct? How should one go about to think about analyticity in a domain and how to show that?

Comment: As a useful tip: if a complex function is differentiable at a point, then it is actually analytic there. Furthermore, if you restrict yourself to real variables, you can expand about any real number $z_0>0$ in Taylor series.

Comment: @Clayton Yes, so I've come to understand. So the function in question is analytic everywhere except z=0? How come Cauchy-Riemann's equations seem to fail then? Mustn't Cauchy-Riemann's equation be satisfied (as well as the functions partial derivatives being continuous) for it to be analytic?

Comment: I think you've just made a computational mistake; it is hard to tell since you didn't post your calculations.

Comment: @Clayton That's quite possible; I will try to do it once more. But, the function is then analytic everywhere except the origin? That is a fact?

Comment: Correct :)${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Cauchy-Reimann's test on $e^z$ and ${1\over z}$ separately and then multiply them together:$$e^z=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y\implies {u=e^x\cos y\\v=e^x\sin y}\\{\partial u\over\partial x}=e^x\cos y\\{\partial u\over\partial y}=-e^x\sin y\\{\partial v\over\partial x}=e^x\sin y\\{\partial v\over\partial y}=e^x\cos y$$therefore$${\partial u\over\partial x}={\partial v\over\partial y}\\{\partial u\over\partial y}=-{\partial v\over\partial x}$$for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$. Similarly$${1\over z}={x\over x^2+y^2}-i{y\over x^2+y^2}$$so we have$${\partial u\over\partial x}={\partial v\over\partial y}={y^2-x^2\over(x^2+y^2)^2}\\{\partial u\over\partial y}=-{\partial v\over\partial x}=-{2xy\over(x^2+y^2)^2}$$as long as $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. Since $e^z$ and $1\over z$ are analytic over $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C-\{0+i0\}$ then their product, ${e^z\over z}$ is analytic over $\Bbb C-\{0\}$.

Comment: Looks excellent! Do you have any source for why they can be calculated separately and then multiplied? Or perhaps an explanation?

Comment: Thank you so much!. In fact my reason was that if a function is analytic in a point $z_0$, then it equals its Taylor's series in that point, i.e.$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$now if two functions $f,g$ have this property (analyticity in $z_0$) then $$f(z)g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(z-z_0)^n$$with$$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$$therefore $f\cdot g(z)$ is also analytic in $z_0$. A same argument holds over an arbitrary domain containing some points. You can also refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: (cont'd) for more information.